# why does this program work??returning local struct variables

Tags: c, function, scope, structure, local-variables

I have the below program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
}point;

point add(int a, int b){
     int c;
     point p1;
     c= a+b;
     p1.x =c;
     p1.y =c;

     return(p1);
}

int main()
{
    int a=20,b=65;
    point k;
    k = add(a,b);


   printf("k.x=%d,k.y=%d\n",k.x,k.y);


   return 0;
}
```

program o/p:

```
 k.x=85,k.y=85
```

In the function add, I'm creating a temporary variable p1 and assigning it values then returning it.In the main function I use the returned value to print the structure members.

My question is how is this possible ?? once I exit the function add, isn't my local variable p1 destroyed? if yes then how am I still able to see the correct values i.e values assigned to p1 ?? what am I missing??

Comment: Return values are passed by value. This means a copy is made which is still valid after you exit from that function

Comment: You are probably mixing with returning the address of a local variable which causes trouble.

Comment: You return the structure itself by value, no more different than returning an integer by value, really.

Comment: You may want to return a pointer to this local variable, *if you really want* the program to crash

Comment: There are even functions in the C standard itself that do exactly this, [such as `div_t div(int numer, int denom);`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.6.2).

Comment: @Gerhardh thankyou!  so when you say a copy is made are you saying somewhere say cpy_p is made and its stored there then p is destroyed and k in the main function access cpy_p?? if yes how does it know where cpy_p is ??

Comment: @JenyaP There is no cpy_p... p1 is copied *into* k directly right *before* being destroyed...

Comment: The compiler knows how parameters are passed to a function and how return values are passed to the caller. It's either defined by the compiler or there might be some ABI specification for the given CPU or architecture. There is probably some space on the stack reserved where the return value is copied to before the function jumps back.

Comment: @Gerhardh that was very insightful! so what you mean to say : p in this case is copied on to the stack before function returns , latter k access this value on the stack which is used to assign its members , have I understood it correct??

Comment: Yes, in general that's correct. The code calling the function knows where the return value is and can copy it into `k`. Basically, the compiler creates the code, that is how the compiler knows where the result is stored and can be retrieved after the function finished.

Comment: @Gerhardh Ooh ok.. thank you  so much you've been very helpful !! honestly if I had enough points I would have up voted your comments either ways a +1!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return p1;` takes a value copy of `p1` that can be used at the calling site. (For a large `struct`, that can be quite expensive computationally but I wouldn't worry about that here - if you are in any doubt profile the performance.)

You are correct in saying that the `p1` declared in the function is destroyed, but that happens after the copy.

(I've intentionally removed the parentheses around the return variable as keeping them is poor style.)

Comment: It's only poor style in C++, if I may nitpick.

Comment: @StoryTeller Hm, wherever I've been so far, Bathsheba's oppinion has been common sense in both C and C++...

Comment: Some say `return x * y;` is less readable and prefer `return (x * y);`. Some say `return(x);` looks like a "function call" and prefer `return x;` instead. In any case, the "preference" is very subjective and not necessarily "poor style".

Comment: @P.P. This is gonna cost me, but the `(ret)` style can be harmful in C++. Yes they are two separate languages, but a fair bit of C++ code starts off as C code. You don't know where your code is going to end up. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Aconcagua - There is no semantic reason to favor one over the other in C. It is ultimately about taste. In C++ it can break you generic functions, so there's that.

Comment: @StoryTeller Just as if I would call any function like this: `void f(int, int); void g(void) { f((10), (12)); }` - no semantic reason either not to prefer that one...

Comment: @Aconcagua - No. It's the semantic difference between [correct code and undefined behavior](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ReuGlzOEXYpvosZe). Anyway, I bothered Bathsheba enough, so I won't be discussing it further.

Comment: @Bathsheba thankyou! but I'm unclear about this line you stated " p1 declared in the function is destroyed, but that happens after the copy." could you please elaborate? are you trying to say p1 is first copied to k in main and then its destroyed??

Comment: @StoryTeller Too bad, would have been really curious to see your wand box sample, unfortunately, just seeing blank panel... Undefined behaviour? By adding surplus(obsolete) parentheses???

Comment: @Aconcagua - Sigh... of course I'll mess up the link. Here is another attempt at [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zjLjkmlMifWiJk4u) and [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/749474cde10650b8) to boot.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah, C++... I am aware of this little pitfall, was referring to C, though, as we agreed with Bathsheba on the C++ case already... My fault, was not clear enough about. BTW: wandbox still not working, but coliru...

Answer (score 0):

In your add(int a, int b) method, you are returning a struct variable. In your main method, you are storing the same returned value in another point variable(k). which copies your struct value in k. Hence, you are able to access the values in your printf function.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the local variable from `add()` . Instead, you are copying the local variable into k.

The copy of `point p1` is returned and not the `point p1` itself